# regex to select only the zipcode

Tags: regex

,Ray Balwierczak,4/11/2017,,895 Forest Hill Rd,Apalachin,NY,13732,y,,

i want to select only 13732 from the line. I came up with this regex

(\d)(\s*\d+)*(\,y,,)

But its also selecting the ,y,, .if i remove it that part from regex, the regex also gets valid for the date. please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you want to match something without capturing it, use zero-length *lookaround* (lookahead or lookbehind). In your case, you can use lookahead:

```
(\d)(\s*\d+)*(?=\,y,,)
```

The syntax `(?=<stuff>)` means "followed by `<stuff>`, without matching it".

More information on lookarounds can be found in [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Regex:** `\D*(\d{5})\D*`

**Explanation:** match 5 digits surrounded by zero or more non-digits on both sides. Then you can extract group containing the match.

**Here's code in python:**

```
import re
string = ",Ray Balwierczak,4/11/2017,,895 Forest Hill Rd,Apalachin,NY,13732,y,,"
search = re.search("\D*(\d{5})\D*", string)
print search.group(1)
```

**Output:** 
13732